# create statement does not work with replace function

Tags: hive, hiveql, create-table

I have the following query which is actually working:

```
SELECT replace(z.PRODUCT_TITLE,'''','') as PRODUCTTITLE, z.NICK FROM table1 z WHERE NICK<=200
```

But when I execute the same query with create statement I get the following error:

create table table2 as

```
SELECT replace(z.PRODUCT_TITLE,'''','') as PRODUCTTITLE, z.NICK FROM table1 z WHERE NICK<=200
```

> ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 40000, SQL state: 
>   TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS,
>   infoMessages:[*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error
>   while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Invalid
>   function 'replace':17:16,
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:toSQLException:Operation.java:400,
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:prepare:SQLOperation.java:187,
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:runInternal:SQLOperation.java:271,
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:run:Operation.java:337......

So, even if the create statement does not support replace function, I should create this table somehow. Can you think of something more suitable in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try regexp_replace function:

```
 select regexp_replace(z.PRODUCT_TITLE,'\\'','')  --removes single-quote character
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a reason why replace function does not work in this case?

Comment: @MuratAdilCanYıldız I do not know the reason. replace added in Hive 1.3, previously it was only regexp_replace. Maybe it is some bug